# $\overline{X\setminus (A\cup B)}=X\setminus(\text{int}(A)\cup\text{int}(B))$

Tags: general-topology

I believe that this is false. As a counterexample, I selected

$X=\mathbb{R}$

$A=[0,1]$

$B=[1,2]$

So then

$\overline{X\setminus(A\cup B)}=(-\infty,0]\cup[2,\infty)$

$X\setminus (\text{int}\ A\cup\text{int}\ B)=(-\infty,0]\cup[2,\infty)\cup\{1\}$

Does this work?

Comment: Yes, it is a perfect counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for checking this @Berci

Comment: This is true in an arbitrary topological space $X$. Let $A$ and $B$ be closed sets with a point $p$ in common that is not in the interior of $A$ or $B$. Then $p\in X\setminus A\cup B)$ so $p\notin \overline{X\setminus (A\cup B)}$, but $p\notin A^\circ\cup B^\circ$, so $p\in X\setminus (A^\circ\cup B^\circ)$.

Comment: @Math1000: Such a counterexample doesn't exist in all topological spaces. For example in the discrete topology, closure and interior are identity functions, and therefore the equality holds trivially.

Comment: @celtschk Good point. What conditions on $X$ are necessary for the counterexample to exist?

Comment: @Math1000: Thinking about it, all you need is a set $M$ that is not clopen. Then you get a counterexample by taking for $A$ and $B$ the closures of the interior and the exterior of that set: Then $\overline{X\setminus(A\cup B)}$ is empty, but $X\setminus(A^\circ\cup B^\circ)$ is the border of the set. Thus the discrete topology is the only topology without a counterexample.

Comment: By "border" you mean "boundary," correct?

Comment: @Math1000: Yes, I meant the boundary.

Comment: Good. Another counter-example is $X=\Bbb R, A=\Bbb Q, B=X\setminus A.$